# How to make media section?

Tags: wordpress, media

Many Wordpress themes have a section that contain gallery, images, video etc.
I want to create something like this. But I don't know how should I do it.
Should I create a custom post type for this media section only and then query it?
Should I query posts from default post type? 
Or just create a static page with media items and then include it to the homepage?
Maybe create a shortcode?
What is the most appropriate way to do this? How the most of developers do it?
Please, help me.

Answer (score 0):

There are many free and premium gallery plugins available for same work. All you have to do is implement the shortcode in your page where you want to display the media,

Comment: Thank you for answer. But is there any way to do it without plugins?

Comment: Yes, you can create a custom post type for medias and create a template for your media gallery, link it to a page and loop through the post to display your media.

Comment: Is this the way that developers usually do? Or there can also be most appropriate option?

Comment: No option is the best option. Every developer has their own taste and set of skills. Some feel this way more than other. Some goes all the way around.
It's Just what makes your work easy.. :)

Happy coding...